# How to resolve Android Build error "Your build is currently configured to use Java 19 and Gradle 7.5."

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My Android project was building fine with the following project build file

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.4.0-alpha02'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.0-alpha10' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.0-alpha10' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.21' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.44.2' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

my Android Studio version is

```
Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Canary 10
Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.9409768, built on December 15, 2022
Runtime version: 17.0.4.1+0-17.0.4.1b469.62-9127311 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 10.15.7
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 12
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    gradle.version.catalogs.dynamic.support=true
    ide.images.show.chessboard=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.android.aas (3.5.1)
    com.jetbrains.kmm (0.5.1(222)-30)
```

My Android application is a multi module project with each module setting the following java/kotlin options

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '11'
    freeCompilerArgs += [
            "-opt-in=androidx.compose.material3.windowsizeclass.ExperimentalMaterial3WindowSizeClassApi"]
}
```

Within my Android Studio preferences I set `Gradle JDK: Java 18`

However when I make the following change to my app gradle build file

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '11'
    freeCompilerArgs += [
            "-opt-in=androidx.compose.material3.windowsizeclass.ExperimentalMaterial3WindowSizeClassApi",
            "-opt-in=kotlinx.coroutines.ObsoleteCoroutinesApi",
    ]
}
```

e.g. add this additional `-opt-in` entry `"-opt-in=kotlinx.coroutines.ObsoleteCoroutinesApi",`

my build fails with

```
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 3 s 350 ms

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file '/Users/anonymous/github/mobile-android-app/app/build.gradle' (/Users/beecheya/.gradle/caches/7.5/scripts/3am3ttbat0qsqgsjlhtiaj5se).
   > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 63
```

and also

```
Unsupported Java. 
Your build is currently configured to use Java 19 and Gradle 7.5.

Possible solution:
 - Open Gradle wrapper settings, change `distributionUrl` property to use compatible Gradle version and reload the project
```

my gradle wrapper contents resemble this:-

```
#Tue Oct 25 07:38:32 BST 2022
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

How do i resolve this build error?

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to Gradle 7.6 that has Java 19 support.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/release-notes.html#java19